# pandas read_sql. How to query with where clause of date field

Tags: python, sql, oracle, date

I have a field month-year which is in datetime64[ns] format.

How do i use this field in where clause to get rolling 12 months data(past 12 months data).

Below query does not work, but I would like something that filters data for 12 months.

```
select * from ABCD.DEFG_TABLE where monthyear > '2019-01-01'
```

FYI -  It is an oracle database. If i can avoid hard coding the value 2019-01-01 that would be great!!

Comment: Please tag the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oracle...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pure SQL.

The following expression dynamically computes the beginning of the months 1 year ago:

```
add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -12)
```

This phrases as: take the date at the first day of the current month, and withdraw 12 months from it.

You can just use it as a filter condition:

```
select * from ABCD.DEFG_TABLE where monthyear > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -12)
```

NB: this assumes that `monthyear` is of datatype `date`.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks GMB. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the datetime and set the date format as below.

Just get your relative date and if you follow datetime format as YYYYMMDD, use strftime from date time with regex string as ("%Y%m%d")

```
import datetime
import pandas 
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


query = "SELECT * FROM ng_scott.Emp"

between_first = datetime.date.today()
between_second = between_first - relativedelta(years=1)


# GET THE DATASET
dataset = pd.read_sql(query , con=engine)

# PARSE THE DATASET
filtered_dataset = dataset[(dataset['DOJ'] > between_first ) & (dataset['DOJ'] > between_second )]

print(filtered_dataset)
```

Comment: Suganth, Thanks for the reply. Your code does work, but I was looking to filter the data in the query statement rather than bring the entire data set and then filtering.

Comment: Glad to help. Your title showed pandas read_sql, So I assumed you wanted a solution related to pandas. You can achieve this by Altering your query alone, Let me know if you need any help in the dynamic query Statement creation.

I can post you another answer